# How to select the highest number of occurances for a certain text value?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to find the person who has drank most beer types from USA. The result should be just be the name of that person alone and not include a count column. How should I perform the select statement?
The result should look like this:

```
name
Alan
```

The table above should be acquired from the table below:

```
sysnr       beer              country        name
----------  ----------------  ----------  ----------
1260        Guinness Draught  Irland      Agneta
11226       Gigantic IPA      USA         Alan
11410       Alesmith Decaden  USA         Alan
11581       Trashy Blonde     Storbritan  Alan
1260        Guinness Draught  Irland      Alan
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Alan
1416        Lowenbrau         Tyskland    Alan
1506        Jever             Tyskland    Alan
1515        Punk IPA          Storbritan  Alan
1523        Armageddon IPA    Nya Zeelan  Alan
1540        Westmalle Double  Belgien     Alan
1548        Brooklyn Lager    USA         Alan
1553        Chang Beer        Thailand    Alan
1559        Coors Light       USA         Alan
1565        Bitburger         Tyskland    Alan
1565        Bitburger         Tyskland    Alan
1566        Pilsner Urquell   Tjeckien    Alan
1574        Pabst Blue Ribbo  USA         Alan
1585        San Miguel        Spanien     Alan
1594        Lapin Kulta       Finland     Alan
1625        Sierra Nevada Pa  USA         Alan
1642        Fullers London P  Storbritan  Alan
1649        Samuel Adams Bos  USA         Alan
1650        Orval             Belgien     Alan
1654        Duvel             Belgien     Alan
1657        Chimay vit        Belgien     Alan
1659        Leffe Blond       Belgien     Alan
1664        Kwak              Belgien     Alan
1670        DAB               Tyskland    Alan
1670        DAB               Tyskland    Alan
1675        Anchor Steam Bee  USA         Alan
89607       Lagunitas IPA     USA         Alan
89793       Maredsous Tripel  Belgien     Alan
11410       Alesmith Decaden  USA         Dick
1553        Chang Beer        Thailand    Dick
1642        Fullers London P  Storbritan  Dick
1222        Sofiero           Sverige     Dina
1574        Pabst Blue Ribbo  USA         Dina
1650        Orval             Belgien     Dina
11451       Pripps Bla        Sverige     Fredrik
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Fredrik
1559        Coors Light       USA         Fredrik
30611       Dugges High Five  Sverige     Fredrik
11489       Gambrinus         Tjeckien    Henrik
1353        Budvar            Tjeckien    Henrik
1544        Litovel Classic   Tjeckien    Henrik
1566        Pilsner Urquell   Tjeckien    Henrik
1611        Breznak           Tjeckien    Henrik
89301       Bernard           Tjeckien    Henrik
11410       Alesmith Decaden  USA         Janne
1260        Guinness Draught  Irland      Janne
1506        Jever             Tyskland    Janne
1559        Coors Light       USA         Janne
1559        Coors Light       USA         Janne
1649        Samuel Adams Bos  USA         Janne
11410       Alesmith Decaden  USA         Johan
1515        Punk IPA          Storbritan  Johan
1548        Brooklyn Lager    USA         Johan
1559        Coors Light       USA         Johan
1670        DAB               Tyskland    Johan
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Jonas
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Juha
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Juha
1522        Karhu             Finland     Juha
1523        Armageddon IPA    Nya Zeelan  Juha
1566        Pilsner Urquell   Tjeckien    Juha
1574        Pabst Blue Ribbo  USA         Juha
1594        Lapin Kulta       Finland     Juha
30023       US Red Ale        Finland     Juha
30658       Stigbergets Sais  Sverige     Juha
11433       Falcon Export     Sverige     Kalle
1519        Saxon             Finland     Kalle
1522        Karhu             Finland     Kalle
1551        Citra Pale Ale    Holland     Kalle
1594        Lapin Kulta       Finland     Kalle
1675        Anchor Steam Bee  USA         Kalle
30023       US Red Ale        Finland     Kalle
11433       Falcon Export     Sverige     Kjell
1515        Punk IPA          Storbritan  Kjell
1548        Brooklyn Lager    USA         Kjell
1559        Coors Light       USA         Kjell
11226       Gigantic IPA      USA         Lennart
11451       Pripps Bla        Sverige     Lennart
11489       Gambrinus         Tjeckien    Lennart
11581       Trashy Blonde     Storbritan  Lennart
1344        Amstel            Holland     Lennart
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Lennart
1407        Backyard Brew     Danmark     Lennart
1523        Armageddon IPA    Nya Zeelan  Lennart
1540        Westmalle Double  Belgien     Lennart
1565        Bitburger         Tyskland    Lennart
1566        Pilsner Urquell   Tjeckien    Lennart
1574        Pabst Blue Ribbo  USA         Lennart
1594        Lapin Kulta       Finland     Lennart
1642        Fullers London P  Storbritan  Lennart
1650        Orval             Belgien     Lennart
1659        Leffe Blond       Belgien     Lennart
1664        Kwak              Belgien     Lennart
1670        DAB               Tyskland    Lennart
89793       Maredsous Tripel  Belgien     Lennart
1403        Tuborg            Danmark     Lisen
1407        Backyard Brew     Danmark     Lisen
1548        Brooklyn Lager    USA         Lisen
1553        Chang Beer        Thailand    Lisen
1565        Bitburger         Tyskland    Lisen
1594        Lapin Kulta       Finland     Lisen
1657        Chimay vit        Belgien     Lisen
30611       Dugges High Five  Sverige     Lisen
30658       Stigbergets Sais  Sverige     Lisen
11410       Alesmith Decaden  USA         Magnus
1260        Guinness Draught  Irland      Magnus
1407        Backyard Brew     Danmark     Maria
11451       Pripps Bla        Sverige     Marie
11489       Gambrinus         Tjeckien    Rikard
1353        Budvar            Tjeckien    Rikard
1540        Westmalle Double  Belgien     Rikard
1544        Litovel Classic   Tjeckien    Rikard
1611        Breznak           Tjeckien    Rikard
1650        Orval             Belgien     Rikard
1654        Duvel             Belgien     Rikard
1657        Chimay vit        Belgien     Rikard
1659        Leffe Blond       Belgien     Rikard
1664        Kwak              Belgien     Rikard
1670        DAB               Tyskland    Rikard
89793       Maredsous Tripel  Belgien     Rikard
11410       Alesmith Decaden  USA         Urban
1416        Lowenbrau         Tyskland    Urban
1506        Jever             Tyskland    Urban
1565        Bitburger         Tyskland    Urban
1642        Fullers London P  Storbritan  Urban
1670        DAB               Tyskland    Urban
```

Appriciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` if you want one result (even when there are ties):

```
select name  -- , count(*) you don't need the count(*) here, but I would keep it
from t
where country = 'USA'
group by name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all rows when there are ties, then use window functions:

```
select name
from (select name, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by country order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where country = 'USA'
      group by name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the count column appears, which I do not want. Just the name alone. Is it even possbile?

Comment: Shouldn't the window function one use `DESC` too?

Comment: The thing with these queries is that they don't have any relation to the country USA. If I increased the limit to 2, itd display alan and Lennart. If I increased it to 3, itd show Alan, Lennart and Rikard. Its just a coincidence that those names appear at the top in the name column no? Because Lennart definetly hasnt drank 2nd most number of beers from the u.s

Comment: @Zerenity ... That needs a `WHERE` condition.